# ¿Cómo usar procedimientos y funciones?

Tags: python-3.x, vectores

Estoy comenzando con vectores y matrices en Python. Quiero introducir un vector y luego mostrarlo. Me gustaría hacerlo con procedimientos y funciones

```
import time
print("VECTORES Y MATRICES")

print("INTRO N\n")

N = int(input())
V = [None]*(N+1)

for I in range (0,N,1):
    V[I] = int(input("Ingrese numero "))
    
print ("VECTOR RESULTANTE: \n")
I=0
print (V[I:N])

time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu pregunta no se entiende.. podrias aclarar mucho mejor tu problema?

Answer (score 3):

Tu código no es muy "pythonico". Veamos que mejoras se le pueden hacer.

La convención es usar minúsculas para todo. Sólo los nombres de las clases comienzan con mayúsculas.

Más importante, en Python no se reserva espacio para los arreglos; simplemente se crea una lista vacía y se le van agregando elementos.

La función `range`, que ocuparas a menudo, la mayor parte del tiempo se ocupa simplemente dando el valor final. Si se omiten, el valor inicial es cero y el avance es uno. En lugar de escribir

```
for i in range (0,n,1):
```

basta con

```
for i in range(n):
```

Cuando quieres usar la lista (arreglo, vector) completo, basta con poner el nombre. No necesitas indicar ningún rango. No es necesario decir

```
I=0
print (V[I:N])
```

basta con

```
print(v)
```

**Funciones**

En Python sólo hay funciones; no existe la distinción función-procedimiento.

El código se puede reorganizar definiendo una función para ingresar el vector, lo que simplifica la vida si tienes que ingresar más de uno.

En este código, la función `ingresa_vector` pide el número de elementos que contendrá y luego pide los valores.

En lugar de usar `int` para ingresar los valores, usamos `float`, que es más general.

Para guiar al usuario, se le va diciendo que elemento está ingresando (el primero, segundo, ...)

La función retorna el vector ingresado.

```
def ingresa_vector():
    vector = []
    n = int(input("Ingrese el largo del vector: "))
    for i in range(n):
        v = float(input(f"Ingrese elemento {i+1} = "))
        vector.append(v)
    return vector

print("VECTORES Y MATRICES")
mi_vector = ingresa_vector()
print("vector resultante:")
print(mi_vector)
```

produce:

```
VECTORES Y MATRICES
>>>Ingrese el largo del vector: 3
>>>Ingrese elemento 1 = 9.5
>>>Ingrese elemento 2 = 30.3
>>>Ingrese elemento 3 = 23
vector resultante: 
[9.5, 30.3, 23.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres hacer una matriz puedes utilizar listas bidimensionales, listas dentro de listas.

Te dejo un código de ejemplo:

```
# Creacion de la matriz
m = [[0]]

# Input Usuario para orden de matriz
numeroFilas = int(input("Numero de Filas: "))
numeroColumnas = int(input("Numero de Columnas: "))

# Expandimos la matriz
for i in range(numeroFilas-1):
    m.append([0])
for i in range(numeroFilas):
    for j in range(numeroColumnas-1):
        m[i].append(0)

# Pedimos al usuario que la rellene
for i in range(numeroFilas):
    for j in range(numeroColumnas):
        m[i][j] = input("Introduce el valor para la fila " + str(i+1) + " columna " + str(j+1) + ": ")

# Imprimimos la matriz
for i in range(numeroFilas):
    for j in range(numeroColumnas):
        print(m[i][j], end=" ")
    print("")
```

Para acceder a una variable de la matriz escribes el nombre de la misma, en este caso "m", y a continuación sus índices sea el primero la fila y el segundo la columna.

```
print(m[0][1])
# Imprimirá la variable de la primera fila y segunda columna
```